# MySQL first / last value and calculations with previous value

Tags: mysql, indexing, subquery, calculation

I have huge tables with data rows for each minute. Some columns are calculated with difference of **[last value of interval] - [value of last interval before]**. But is there a way to speed up the query? There is the primary and the date index already. There shouldn't be any additional indexes created.
Currently the query is running around 11s for about 500.000 rows.

The problem is near the calculations with **DATE_SUB()** function.

MySQL: 10.1.44-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.18.04.1

PHP: 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.3

```
*id* || *select_type*      || *table*   || *type* || *possible_keys* || *key* || *key_len* || *ref* || *rows* || *filtered* || *Extra*
1    || PRIMARY            || a10       || ALL    || date            ||       ||           ||       || 513754 || 21.86      || Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
4    || DEPENDENT SUBQUERY || table_min || index  || date            || date  || 5         ||       || 1      || 100.00     || Using where
3    || DEPENDENT SUBQUERY || table_min || index  || date            || date  || 5         ||       || 1      || 100.00     || Using where
2    || DEPENDENT SUBQUERY || table_min || index  || date            || date  || 5         ||       || 1      || 100.00     || Using where
```

Query:

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED 
SELECT  SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS tm.date,
CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(tm.DB223_DBD10_float ORDER BY  tm.date DESC),
                ",", 1) AS double
    ) AS `10-44-2`,
                CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(tm.DB223_DBD14_float ORDER BY  tm.date DESC),
                ",", 1) AS double) AS `10-45-3`, MIN(tm.DB221_DBD218_float
                    ) AS `10-2-4`,
                MAX(tm.DB221_DBD218_float) AS `10-2-5`, MIN(tm.DB221_DBD222_float) AS `10-3-6`,
MAX(tm.DB221_DBD222_float) AS `10-3-7`, MIN(tm.DB221_DBD278_float) AS `10-4-8`,
MAX(tm.DB221_DBD278_float) AS `10-4-9`, (CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(tm.DB222_DBD10_integer
                                    ORDER BY  tm.date DESC), ",", 1) AS double) - 
            (
                SELECT  DB222_DBD10_integer
                    FROM  table_min
                    WHERE  date <= DATE_SUB(tm.date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
                    ORDER BY  date DESC
                LIMIT  1)
   ) AS `10-18-10`,
                    (CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(tm.DB222_DBD46_integer
       ORDER BY  tm.date DESC),
                        ",", 1) AS double) - (
                SELECT  DB222_DBD46_integer
                    FROM  table_min
                    WHERE  date <= DATE_SUB(tm.date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
                    ORDER BY  date DESC
                LIMIT  1)
                    ) AS `10-36-11`,
                    (CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(tm.DB222_DBD50_integer
       ORDER BY  tm.date DESC),
                        ",", 1) AS double
                          ) - (
                SELECT  DB222_DBD50_integer
                    FROM  table_min
                    WHERE  date <= DATE_SUB(tm.date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
                    ORDER BY  date DESC
                LIMIT  1)
                    ) AS `10-37-12`,
                CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(tm.DB223_DBD124_float
       ORDER BY  tm.date DESC),
                ",", 1) AS double
                    ) AS `10-47-13`,
                CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(tm.DB223_DBD120_float
       ORDER BY  tm.date DESC),
                ",", 1) AS double
                    ) AS `10-46-14`,
                CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(tm.DB223_DBD128_float
       ORDER BY  tm.date DESC),
                ",", 1) AS double
                    ) AS `10-48-15`,
                CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(tm.DB223_DBD132_float
       ORDER BY  tm.date DESC),
                ",", 1) AS double
                    ) AS `10-49-17`,
                CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(tm.DB223_DBD136_float
       ORDER BY  tm.date DESC),
                ",", 1) AS double
                    ) AS `10-50-18`,
                CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(tm.DB223_DBD140_float
       ORDER BY  tm.date DESC),
                ",", 1) AS double
                    ) AS `10-51-19`,
                CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(tm.DB223_DBD144_float
       ORDER BY  tm.date DESC),
                ",", 1) AS double
                    ) AS `10-52-21`,
                CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(tm.DB223_DBD148_float
       ORDER BY  tm.date DESC),
                ",", 1) AS double
                    ) AS `10-53-22`,
                CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(tm.DB223_DBD310_float
       ORDER BY  tm.date DESC),
                ",", 1) AS double
                    ) AS `10-54-24`,
                CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(tm.DB223_DBD314_float
       ORDER BY  tm.date DESC),
                ",", 1) AS double
                    ) AS `10-55-25`,
                    (CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(tm.DB223_DBD310_float
       ORDER BY  tm.date DESC),
                        ",",
                                                ",", 1) AS double),NULL)) AS `10-0-26`,
                        1) AS double)/NULLIF(CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(tm.DB223_DBD314_float
       ORDER BY  tm.date DESC),
CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(tm.DB221_DBD538_float
       ORDER BY  tm.date DESC),
                ",", 1) AS double) AS `10-31-27`,
                MIN(tm.DB221_DBD326_float) AS `10-9-28`,
                MAX(tm.DB221_DBD326_float) AS `10-9-29`,
                MIN(tm.DB221_DBD450_float) AS `10-29-30`,
                MAX(tm.DB221_DBD450_float) AS `10-29-31`,
                MIN(tm.DB221_DBD406_float) AS `10-27-32`,
                MAX(tm.DB221_DBD406_float) AS `10-27-33`,
                MIN(tm.DB221_DBD562_float) AS `10-41-34`,
                MAX(tm.DB221_DBD562_float) AS `10-41-35`
    FROM  table_min AS tm WHERE  tm.date>="2020-01-01 00:00"
      AND  tm.date<="2020-01-31 23:59:59"
    GROUP BY  YEAR(tm.date), MONTH(tm.date), DAY(tm.date)
    ORDER BY  tm.date
    LIMIT  0,20
```

SQL dump of data starting this year:
https://www.tds-net.de/table_min.zip

Comment: Specify MySQL version.

Comment: Sorry, added to question text.

Comment: Please add data to your question and wanted result from the provided data. if you are interested in soving it youself see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/window-functions-overview/

Comment: SQL dump added as ZIP file (~120.000 lines).

Answer (score 0):

- 2 Unique keys.  Perhaps you can get rid of `id` and promote `date` to PK?
- `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` forces going through all the selected rows.  Can you get rid of that?
- `LIMIT 0,20` -- Is that a prelude to "pagination"?  If so, it is much more efficient to [remember where you left off](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination) .
- `GROUP BY YEAR(tm.date), MONTH(tm.date), DAY(tm.date)  ORDER BY tm.date` probably leads to two sorts.  (See `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...` to verify.  This would, I think, avoid the second sort, be simpler, but maybe not much faster:  `GROUP BY DATE(tm.date)  ORDER BY DATE(tm.date)` .  Note that they now say the same thing, thereby avoiding the extra sort.
- `SELECT tm.date ... GROUP BY ...` is improper; change that one, too.
- Get the data first, *then* pivot.  (This will involve another level of nested `SELECTs`.)
- It *may* be better to get the 3 values from statements like into a single query.  But I don't know the best way to fold it back in.

  ```
              SELECT  DB222_DBD10_integer
                  FROM  table_min
                  WHERE  date <= DATE_SUB(tm.date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
                  ORDER BY  date DESC
              LIMIT  1)
  ```

Comment: - Can't get rid of ID because date column is filled via cronjob that aggregates date and writes back to main table (complexity, avoiding duplicates)

- SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS and LIMIT is needed for paginating, new data is filled in every minute so pair of ID and date column can change

- the user can change interval (min, qhour, hour, day, week, month) so GROUP clause is needed

- Why ```SELECT tm.date``` is improper? I need the date and the addtional fields.

- ```... then pivot.```That means to build up logic in e.g. PHP instead of MySQL?

Comment: The problem of time is the select with ```WHERE date <= DATE_SUB(tm.date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)```. If that query is dropped query is running fast.

Comment: @TDS - Without the total number of rows, you stop when there are no more.  "left off" replaces `OFFSET` in pagination.  Read about "only_full_group_by".

Comment: If I understand it right for pagination: add ```INDEX (id, date)```, find first date which fits with ```LIMIT 1``` and then query all other data with ```date > first date``` and ```LIMIT X``` instead ```LIMIT X, Y```?

Comment: @TDS - `LIMIT X` says "deliver the first X rows"; `LIMIT X,Y` says "Skip X rows, then deliver Y rows".

Comment: That's clear. But because of having date as an Index it should be fast enough to skip X rows before instead having index (id, date) and id > X. I tested a rewrote of my query and there is no huge difference (<100ms, >500.000 rows).

Comment: @TDS - `OFFSET` has no shortcut -- it walks through the rows until it has counted off, and tossed, that many rows.  Let's see the rewrite.@TDS